# Trying to merge vertices on all individual meshes in a scene

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, scene

I'm starting scripting and would like to merge the vertices of all the individual mesh objects in my blender scene. So far I've got this script. It runs but doesn't process the meshes. It doesn't select any verts to apply the remove doubles command to. It always says: "Info: Removed 0 vertice(s)". Note:the variable x is to stop it after first 10 meshes (3000 meshes in scene).

```
import bpy
x = 0
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        #print("mesh")
        print(obj.name)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        print("-done")
        x=x+1
    if x > 10:
        break
print ("finished2.2")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy

ojs = bpy.data.objects

# make sure you are in object mode first
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # deselect all object

x = 1
for oj in ojs:
    if oj.type == 'MESH':
        print(f"MESH object: {oj.name}")
        oj.select_set(True)

    if x == 11:
        # need a active object to join
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = oj
        break
    x += 1

bpy.ops.object.join()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

# Adjust threshold to suitable value if vertices are too far
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.0001, use_unselected=False, use_sharp_edge_from_normals=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you just select the object in data, but it don't mean the object is selected in the viewport.So, just add 1 line to active it works.

```
import bpy
x = 0
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        #what you should add
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active=obj
        #print("mesh")
        print(obj.name)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        print("-done")
        x=x+1
    if x > 10:
        break
print ("finished2.2")
```